# Does Processes on Host Machine Affect Virtual Machine?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, virtual-machine, vmware

I use Windows 8.1 as host and Ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare.

I am going to run computational simulations in Java.

I have two questions:
1. If I run simulations on VM and do other works on host machine, does this effect the performance of VM?
2. Is it better to run simulations on host machine or virtual machine, in terms of performance?

Comment: In terms of raw performance, the host is always better, and yes, load created by either the host or the guest will affect the other's hardware share. Personally, I'd forgo the performance and focus on reliability, and from that regard a VM that you can start running and then disconnect from is less likely to be interfered with by other processes, even if its recieving less hardware share. if its really a problem though, perhaps this is a task that either requires better hardware that can support multiple VMs, or just running it on a different physical system.

Comment: We need more details. Is your Host CPU dual core or quad core? How much RAM does your Host have? Are your Virtual Machines configured as single-core virtual CPU? How many Virtual Machines are you intending to run simultaneously? Are the simulations CPU-intensive, RAM-intensive, or both? What kind of work are you intending to do on the Host while simulations are running in the Virtual Machines? With all of these variables in the mix you'd be better off doing some real-word tests for yourself. All you need is a pen, paper, and stopwatch ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. If I run simulations on VM and do other works on host machine, does this effect the performance of VM?

Since the VM is sharing the hosts' resources to exist, then the more host resources you assign to other tasks the less that will be available to the VM. Less resources = less performance.

> 2. Is it better to run simulations on host machine or virtual machine, in terms of performance?

On the host, since you can free the resources being used to create/power the VM (by shutting down the VM).

Depending on what "computational simulations" you are running you may not notice any difference either way.